# private method `select' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models: comments and questions. I am trying to show the last 2 comments on the question page.

Heres the line:

```
<% @comment.select(:body).order('created_at desc').limit(2).each do |comment| %>
<%= @comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting this error:

```
private method `select' called for #<Comment:0x0000010465ac70>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `send`: `@comment.send( :select, :body ) # etc.`

Comment: This gives me a 'wrong argument type Symbol (expected Array)' error.

Comment: In that case, type `@comment.method( :select ).source_location`, open the indicated file, and see what kind of arguments are required by the `select` method of the `Comment` class. You as the user must know what arguments do you want to call your methods with.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying last 2 comments of a question.

Associations:
  question has_many comments

```
@question.comments.select("body").order("created_at desc").limit(2).each do |comment|
  comment.body
end
```

Comment: Hmm, this gives me a 'undefined method `comments'' error. Should is still have question has_many comments when questions belong to comments?

Comment: you must define your @question = Question.where(:id => params[:id])

Comment: Yes, you need the has_many :comments in the Question model for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this right, but I think you better to prepare all on our controller, so the view just for showing it up. It would make your view render faster. But please correct me if I'm wrong. I think the answer from @joreal is quite right. Have you done tried this?

**Model: question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  # some more code
end
```

**Controller: questions_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @question.comments.order(:created_at).limit(2).reverse_order

  # some more code
end
```

**View: views/questions/show.html.erb**

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

This way was more DRY and faster, please is there anything wrong, I would updated the answer. And I think there is a typo on your code.

```
<%= @comment.body %>
```

should be

```
<%= comment.body %>
```

Because it called your alias `|comment|` not your variable anymore `@comment`. Also because you done called `comment.body`, I don't think you're need to `.select(:body)` on your query anymore.

Hope can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which is a lot cleaner. Unfortunately now i am getting an 'undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass' from the controller.

Comment: try to trace that `params` that sent from your previous view. I mean, `params[:id]` can be `params[:something]` based on what you called your `id`. Can you follow that?

Comment: Oops i forgot to add that first ine to the controller. Now i'm getting 'Couldn't find Question without an ID' even though my previous views have the same params [:id].

Comment: can you give me what `params` that sent when you called your `show` method? Or perhaps your show link, like `<%= link_to 'show', question %>` or some else.

Comment: The params were {"comment_id"=>"39"} which is the correct id comment_id i want.

Comment: yes, so you must use `params[:comment_id]`, if there anything that still concern to discuss let's move to discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40053/discussion-between-user2759575-and-kolonel-peteruk)